# Anchor tag contains font not displayed properly if converted in @Html.ActionLink

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, html.actionlink

HTML Code: `<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary next-step"><i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Next1</a>`

Display in UI: [image]

CSHTML Code:

```
@Html.ActionLink("'far fa - arrow - alt - circle - right'></i> Next1", "ActionName", new { controller = "MyController", id = 1 },
                                       new { @class = "btn btn-primary next-step" })
```

But Display in UI is: [image]

On conversion from HTML to @Html.ActionLink should be same in appearance. Help please.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the `@Html.ActionLink` inside the `<i>` tag instead, something like this:

```
<i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-right">
    @Html.ActionLink("Next1", "ActionName", new { controller = "MyController", id = 1 },
    new { @class = "btn btn-primary next-step" })
</i>
```